# Using credential obtained from SSO to authenticate against a 3rd party system

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, integration, saml, enterprise

In an entreprise environment where apps are all configured to use a SAML SSO provider for authentication, I wondering how third party apps could be authenticated against reusing the initial credentials obtained from a main portal.

To set an example, let's say we have a user facing Jenkins instance.
User connect to it with the entreprise SSO.

From it, they can launch jobs that will in initiate a connection to an Ansible Tower to run an ansible playbook.

This can work using an Ansible Tower's service account token configured on Jenkins.

But sometimes it'd be better to use the end-user ID to launch the Tower playbook, for better permission and identification control.

How would it be possible to access the SSO authentication obtained by Jenkins and use them to authenticate against Ansible Tower in a transparent manner?

There must be a precise technical term and widespred solutions for these typical entreprise integration issues, but I wasn't able to find information on this process.